# How to rotate a JXImageview

Tags: java, swingx

I have a "JXImageView" with a picture and I want to rotate a "JXImageview" but the method "getRotateCounterClockwiseAction () is deprecated" 
What is the correct way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue in SwingX jira that is related to your question. Please take a look at https://java.net/jira/browse/SWINGX-990, to find out why the method you mentioned is marked as deprecated.